# Why it is showing me no player tag found? Are you using a direct reference or an assembly reference in unity, so please anybody tell read my question

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

Actually I am telling that once the player touches this object he should die and back to respawn point and show bloody particle effect
But it didn't find the player tag
And this problem didn't come on coin that the coin should destroy but the coin found out the player tag so why not the enemy (spike)
And here's the coin code which didn't showed me error

The coin Collector worked and didn't tell me the error are you using a direct reference or an assembly reference

Please any expert programmer help this beginner

Comment: No code no clues. We cant tell what you did without details

Comment: As mentioned above, you will need to provide more information/code. When you say the player "touches" the object, do you mean you are checking collisions with colliders? Or getting the distance to the object and running the code then? Are you finding the tag with FindGameObjectWithTag? Or checking tags of objects collided in OnTriggerEnter/OnCollisionEnter? We need more info if you want us to help.